# Horizontal distance between drain pipe and meter base

Tags: drain, meter

I have a 3" cast iron toilet drain pipe that runs vertically inside the wall from a second floor bath down to the main drain under the house.  I am putting a two gang meter base (it's a duplex) on the outside of that wall.  What is the required horizontal distance between the meter base and the pipe?

Thank you!

Comment: 0 inches sounds about right.

Comment: The pipe can be behind the meter base I would not trap plumbing like that but there is no minimum on the other side of a wall.